# Comparing two unidentical data frames and changing the column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames

```
df1 = {'Product1': ['Computer','Phone','Printer'],
       'Price1':   [1200,800,200]
       }


df2= {'Product2': ['Computer','Phone','Desk','chair'],
      'Price2': [900,800,350,40]
      }
```

I want to compare the two data frames and if there is a match in the Product then concatenate the price along with the product name else keep the product name as in df1.

so the new

```
df1= {'Product1': ['Computer-1200','Phone-800','Printer'],
      'Price1': [1200,800,200]
      }
```

Comment: are they pandas dataframes or dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming they are [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)'s:

```
df1["Product1"] = df1.Product1 + df1.Product1.isin(df2.Product2) *\
                  (' ' + df1.Price1.astype(str))
```

**Output**

```
df1
        Product1  Price1
0  Computer 1200    1200
1      Phone 800     800
2        Printer     200
```

---

If they are `dict`s you can do this:

```
isin = [prod in df2["Product2"] for prod in df1["Product1"]]
df1["Product1"] = [a + b*(' ' + str(c)) \
                   for a,b,c in zip(df1["Product1"], isin, df1["Price1"])]
```

**Output**

```
df1
{'Product1': ['Computer 1200', 'Phone 800', 'Printer'],
 'Price1': [1200, 800, 200]}
```

Comment: Thanks .Yes its a Pandas Data Frame. But when I use your solution it gives me a error "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U20') dtype('<U20') dtype('<U20')"

Comment: @user6167232 try adding `.astype(str)` after every dataframe/series call

Comment: @user6167232 Nice! please consider mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful :)